# How to load WEINRE dynamically?

Tags: javascript, debugging, remote-debugging, weinre

I do not want to include WEINRE script in head section and I would like to load it on demand (on button click). I tried:

```
$.getScript('http://path-to-weinre-script.js#anonymous')
```

After loading WEINRE script client starts to make calls to `/ws/target/t-9X` periodically but there is no active targets in WEINRE console. How can I force WEINRE initialization without adding it to head section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it myself.
The right way to load WEINRE dynamically is:

```
(function(e){e.setAttribute("src","http://ip:port/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous");document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(e);})(document.createElement("script"));void(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted [issue CB-8738 at Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8738) that sounds similar.  Does this resolve your issue?